# Construction of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Given random variables ${(X_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}}$ defined on a probability space, how shall one construct random variables ${(Y_\beta)_{\beta \in B}}$ which induce prespecified probability measures ${(\mu_\beta)_{\beta \in
    B}}$, are both independent within  ${(Y_\beta)_{\beta \in B}}$ themselves and independent with ${(X_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}}$? Obviously, ${(Y_\beta)_{\beta \in B}}$ must also be defined on the same probability space as ${(X_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}}$.

My question comes from [Terrence Tao's blog](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/254a-notes-0-a-review-of-probability-theory/)

> The product measure construction allows us to extend Lemma 4 (**Creating a random variable with a specified distribution**):
>
> Exercise 18 (**Creation of new, independent random variables**) Let ${(X_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}}$ be a family of random variables (not
>       necessarily independent or finite), and let ${(\mu_\beta)_{\beta \in
>     B}}$ be a collection (not necessarily finite) of probability
>       measures ${\mu_\beta}$ on measurable spaces ${R_\beta}$. Then, after
>       extending the sample space if necessary, one can find a family
>       ${(Y_\beta)_{\beta \in B}}$ of independent random variables, such
>       that each ${Y_\beta}$ has distribution ${\mu_\beta}$, and the two
>       families ${(X_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}}$ and ${(Y_\beta)_{\beta \in
>     B}}$ are independent of each other.

My question is the same as how such ${(Y_\beta)_{\beta \in B}}$ are constructed (via
    the product measure construction or some other methods) in the exercise?

We can consider some simpler questions first.

- Given a random variable $X$, how shall one construct another random variable $Y$ which has a prespecified probability measure $\mu$ and is independent from $X$?
- Given a random variable $X$, how shall one construct two random variable $Y_i, i=1,2$, such that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ have prespecified probability measure $\mu_i, i=1,2$ respectively, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent from $X$, and $Y_1$ and $Y_2$  are independent between each other?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: "i.i.d" often refers to a single random variable. Re Monte Carlo: computers are deterministic finite state machines that can only generate pseudorandom numbers that approximate i.i.d (one would need to sample external input like thermal noise to get randomness).

Comment: @alancalvitti: Thanks! (1) I think i.i.d. applies to more than one random variables, and not to a single one. Think of the definition of independence between several r.v.s in terms of the sigma algebras they generate. (2) For constructing i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables defined from [0,1] to {0,1}, see "Proposition 2.8 (Daniell)" on page 4 of http://math.iisc.ernet.in/~manju/ProbTheory/Notes/1-3%20Independence.pdf. Does it belong to Monte Carlo simulation?

Comment: @alancalvitti: I now realize that I messed up constructing independent random variables and simulating independent random variables. They are different tasks. So I edit my post. Your comment addressed simulating independent random variables. I move that part of my question to stat.SE [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49168/how-to-generate-iid-samples-from-the-linear-congruent-method).

Comment: You can do this using the product measure construction.

Comment: @Michael: $X_\alpha$'s are given, so $Y_\beta$'s have to be defined on the same probability space as $X_\alpha$'s. How is the construction done (using product measure construction)? (While you were posting your comment, I was editing my post at the same time.)

Comment: One can define i.i.d with respect to the product measure, or joint distribution, correct?

Comment: @Tim Tao writes "after extending the sample space if necessary", you can in general not use the same sample space. Otherwise the result would be wrong.

Comment: @alancalvitti: The difficult part I think is $X_\alpha$ are given, so $Y_β$'s have to be defined on the same probability space as $X_α$'s. This domain probability space is not necessarily a product measure space.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: So by "extending the sample space if necessarily", does he think that it may be necessary to redefine $X_\alpha$'s by extending their domains to the product measure space of the domains of $X\alpha$'s and the domains of $Y_\beta$'s?

Comment: @Tim Yes. He also explains his notion of extending a probability space in the first section.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Thanks! After extending the domain to product measure space, is it to follow Example 1 on [page 58 of Kai Lai Chung's A Course in Probability Theory](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zu80w7wd40UC&lpg=PP1&dq=kai%20lai%20chung%20probability%20course%20%20google%20book&pg=PA58#v=onepage&q&f=false)?

Comment: @Tim Well, Tao allows for arbitrary many random variables (there could be uncountably many) and that requires arbitrary many factors in the product.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: can the way in Example 1 in Chung's book be generalized to product measure space of infinitly many component spaces, without modification?

Comment: @Michael: let us [continue discussion on this and some other previous questions in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7369/discussion-between-tim-and-michael-greinecker)

Comment: @alan: I would be *very* curious to see **any** legitimate example where *i.i.d.* was used to refer to a single random variable. The very definition of the first two words implies a reference to a collection of them.

Comment: @cardinal, you're right. My background is in systems & control engineering, where we often refer to the entire stochastic process as *the* variable. But agreed that's sloppy.